# GDB how to log exit code?

Tags: gdb

I'm trying to debug PHP segmentation fault in my CI. I managed to get the GDB stacktrace by running phpunit like this:

```
gdb php -ex "run vendor/bin/phpunit" -ex bt -ex quit
```

The problem is that this way I do not know if phpunit succeeded or failed (doesn't matter if it failed with segfault or with test failure). I need to somehow log the exit code of the `vendor/bin/phpunit` command and use it in an `if` statement later - to decide whether or not the build succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that this way I do not know if phpunit succeeded or failed (doesn't matter if it failed with segfault or with test failure)

You can print the value of [`$_exitsignal` variable](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Vars.html). In case of SIGSEGV signal it would be equal to 11. Also you can use `$_isvoid` function to know if the program exited or signalled. For this code:

```
#include <signal.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  raise (SIGSEGV);
  return 0;
}
```

you can invoke gdb this way:

```
$ gdb -q -ex run -ex bt -ex c -ex "print \$_isvoid(\$_exitsignal)" -ex quit a.out 
Reading symbols from a.out...
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7e1e9e5 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#0  0x00007ffff7e1e9e5 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x000000000040113f in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffd6e8) at 1.c:5
Continuing.

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
The program no longer exists.
$1 = 0
```

At the end of output you can see that the program ended with signal, `$_isvoid($_exitsignal)` returned `0`:

```
$1 = 0
```